Error with creation of a new Care Request records in salesforce: two gack ids
STR:

Try to create a new CareRequest record type: DrugRequest record in the sandbox
input name = Test.
=> Obtain
UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 236873532-410686 (-784799458)


STR2.

Execute Apex insert new CareRequest();
Receive
Line: undefined, Column: undefined
Response to EXEC was : ; nested exception is: common.exception.ApiException: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1601008600-390281 (-1594011866). HTTP CODE[500]


Why this error is happening?

Aparently there are required fields which are not marked as required.
CareRequestCaseId is not defined as a required field, neither are member id or member first name or last name.
I have opened a SF Support Case and SF Support representative suggested to add CareRequestCaseId on the layout.
It starts showing meaningful error on the UI once CareRequestCaseId is added to layout.
However, this is strange that CareRequestCaseId can be removed from the layout.
The correct way to create CareRequest from Apex would be
RecordType rt1 = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE Name = 'Drug Request' AND SObjectType = 'Case'][0];
Case c = new Case(RecordTypeId = rt1.Id);
insert c;
RecordType rt = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE Name = 'Drug Request' AND SObjectType = 'CareRequest'][0];
insert new CareRequest(Name = 'test', CareRequestCaseId  = c.Id, MemberIdentificationNumber  = '0', RecordTypeId = rt.Id);


Update as of 31 Dec 2024:
SF Support published a known issue but marked it as working as designed
https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000zkPQI/
